# how can we Convert format Timestamp in java

Tags: java

I connected java with mysql, from where i am getting sql timestamp data = "2021-03-09 14:33:05.095".{TIMESTAMP(0)}
Now i need to store that value into oracle. but in oracle the timestamp format is like : 07-DEC-17 06.16.35.261000000 PM.{TIMESTAMP(6)  }

How can we convert timestamp format?

Comment: It's not clear why the format used by the respective database would matter.  Please update the question with some code which shows the problem.

Comment: You don't convert anything, because you **don't use `String`** to read/write timestamp values from/to the database, you **use a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)** object. Converting to/from a string is done elsewhere in the code that is responsible for displaying the value to the user and retrieving the value from the user, it is not done in the code that interacts with the database.

Comment: The comment by @Andreas is correct. I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Timestamp`. That class is a hack on top of the already poorly designed `java.util.Date` class and long outdated. Instead depending on exact requirements use either `OffsetDateTime` or `LocalDateTime`; both are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

Date-time data types in the database do not have a “format” as they are not textual. To exchange date-time values between database and Java, use date-time objects.

Parse your string input as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2021-03-09 14:33:05.095".replace( " " , "T" ) ) ;
```

Store in the database using a column of a data type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.

- For MySQL, the column must be of type [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html).
- For Oracle DB, the column must be of type [`TIMESTAMP`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6) (*not* `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`).

Send your date-time object.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

One of the comments suggests using `java.sql.Timestamp`. Do *not* do that. That poorly-designed class is obsolete, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

All of this has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Comment: MySQL stores `timestamp` values in UTC, so it should be possible to use `OffsetDateTime` in Java and `timestamp with time zone` in Oracle.